# Select last entry from sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to select the last entry from my database.

```
$sql = "SELECT LAST(time) FROM pikkertonnode_415629569";
$erg = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Can't do it");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($erg))
{
$x = $data['time'];
...
```

Everytime i get the message ,,Can't do it"

Can you help me?

Comment: The latest value of time or the whole row with the latest value of time?

Comment: Do you have to use `mysql_query` for this?

Answer (score 3):

use `MAX`

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(time) AS max_time FROM `pikkertonnode_415629569`"
```

Comment: Yeah ok now i get the latest time ... but i didn't mentioned that i want to read out the whole row. When i make SELECT MAX(time) AS mt, amperage ... i don't get the latest amperage value

Answer (score 2):

If you want the latest complete record and not just the biggest value of one column you can do

```
SELECT * FROM pikkertonnode_415629569
order by `time` desc
limit 1
```

if you have a `time` column actually...